# In dev mode angular2 does 2 cycle check via zone, that will cause an error of: Expression has changed after it was checked error, is it save to

Tags: angular

So I have this directive template

```
<img [src]="getImageUrl()" (load)="onImageLoaded()" (error)="onImageError()" />
```

and if I enableProdMode all is good. If I don't enable enableProdMode I will get 
and error of:

```
browser_adapter.ts:78 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'http://galaxy.signage.me/Resources/Resellers/300762/Logo.jpg?random=' 0.10902238642453255'.
```

which I fully understand because of the zone 2nd check in dev mode.

So as you can see, I change the argument params in my image URL so the browser always gets a fresh one, and it will work fine in production.

But is that safe? I mean the ng2 team put that check on purpose to things don't have side effects, but I am creating a side effect... and if so, really what is the proper way of avoiding this? will detaching the re-attaching the changeDetector really the best way? which I have tried but so far in dev mode still produces the same error (I may need to play with some more)...

Is there a way to listen to the NEXT ApplicationTick and only apply the changes on the next tick, so you don't create a side effect?

regards,

Sean.

Answer (score 1):

It might be safe in this one case but it is inefficient. In other situations not testing in devMode might hide real bugs.

Rather write your code so it works fine in devMode as well.

Comment: my thoughts exactly... I know that in this case it's fine... since I am dealing with an image. but I want to be clean. so is there a way to generally listen to the Application Tick to know when it is safe to apply changes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Its always safe to apply changes except in lifecycle callbacks which are called by change detection (`ngOnChanges', `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterViewInit',...). What causes the error message is that two succesive calls to a bound getter or method returns different values. To avoid it either store the value to a property and bind to thos property or cache the value and return the cached value. Using funtions in value bindings directly is discouraged.

Comment: tx will give it a shot now!

Comment: Is there a way to detect that you are in devMode?  I didn't see any method exposed in https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index.html, which is where `enableProdMode()` is exposed.  If we had a way to detect the mode, we could write `getImageUrl()` to be mode-aware.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. The code should work the same in both modes.

Comment: like Gunter suggested, I did do a workaround with the devMode, but proper way would be to assign to a member which is what I am going to refactor it as... tx

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Answer: use setTimeout();**

**Explanation:**

So I had this issue as well with information in a style property. 
Something like:

```
<div [style.color]="textColor">Cool Colored Text</div>
//Component
public textColor:string = "red";
ngAfterViewInit {
  this.textColor = getColor();
}
```

and I would get the same error saying that it started as "red" but ended up "green" because even though quick, I was in a deeply nested route and a ton of stuff had to fire to get the getColor() which ran async and would trigger between the two checks.

I did a ton of research on why exactly and which lifecycle hook, constructor, or whatever to hook into to have it work correctly and nothing worked until I was digging around in core code and saw a note about some function just being a wrapper around `setTimeout()` to make sure it ran on the next tick.

So I changed my code to:

```
setTimeout(() => this.textColor = getColor();,10);
```

worked like a charm...

I do agree with Gunter, try not to call the function in the template directly (if possible), it's harder to test or be flexible.

if you did `<img [src]="imageUrl" />` 
you could do `imageUrl = getImageUrl()` then later: `imageUrl= getImageUrl(true,false,"whatever")` or even re-use the template and: `imageUrl = totallyOtherGetter();`